# Density operator time evolution in the path integral approach

Tags: path-integral, density-operator

I want to know how the density operator of a system evovles when we use path integral approach.

Comment: If you can access it, you might find [U. Weiss, Quantum Dissipative Systems](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Dissipative-Systems-4th-Edition/dp/9814374911) useful.